# How to set div height on a fixed width div

Tags: jquery, css

I'm coding up a site where I have a fixed width div which represents a photo frame. 
The user can alter the width and height values for the frame, and using Jquery, I'd like to show them a representation of the frame.

The width of the frame div itself is fixed, as there's limited room for it in the page design. So the only dimension that can physically change is the height.

If the user has specified a frame width of 300mm for example, and a height of 200mm, I have to represent that on-screen. What I'm struggling with is getting an accurate representation.
Currently, I'm doing the following:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#artwork_height_input" ).change(function() {
    //Work out the new proportional height (the width of the div is fixed, so only the height can be altered)
    var divWidth = $( "#artwork_width_input" ).val();
    var divHeight = $( "#artwork_height_input" ).val();
    var ratio = divWidth / divHeight;
    var newDivHeight = divHeight / ratio;
    alert(newDivHeight);
    $("#scaledimage").height(newDivHeight-2);
  });
});
```

The problem is, that results in a newDivHeight of 133.33, which I know isn't right. 
Can anyone help me work this one out? I'm sure it's maths more than Jquery but any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: why are there <br> tags in your jquery?

Comment: I removed the `<br>` tags, as I assumed they were just for the purposes of posting the code here.

Comment: Kasper, There aren't - I just put them in so it would format on-screen in StackOverflow. Thanks 'anOG'

Comment: What exactly is your question here? How to get only `integer`-values? That's impossible since division sometimes results in floats.

Comment: If you need integer value use Math.ceil() or Math.floor()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have a problem with the math.

you said that your div has a fixed width, so we need to determine his height.

the frame specified by the user has some ratio, and we need this equation to hold.

`DivHeiht/DivWidth = FrameHeight/FrameWidth`

therefore, `DivHeight = DivWidth*(FrameHeight/Framewidth)`

```
$(function() {
  $( "#artwork_height_input" ).change(function() {
    //Work out the new proportional height (the width of the div is fixed, so only the height can be altered)
    var Framewidth= $("#artwork_width_input").val();
    var FrameHeight= $("#artwork_height_input").val();
    var DivWidth = $("#scaledimage").width();
    var DivHeight = DivWidth*(FrameHeight/Framewidth);
    //alert(DivHeight);
    $("#scaledimage").height(DivHeight);//-2 for what?
  });
});
```

or: the shorter way: (but more difficult to understand)

```
$(function() {
    $( "#artwork_height_input" ).change(function() {
    $("#scaledimage").height($("#scaledimage").width()*$("#artwork_width_input").val()/$("#artwork_height_input").val());});
});
```